# Why do my Review Apps keep failing to build on Heroku Pipelines?

Tags: ruby, heroku, heroku-pipelines

I have a Heroku Pipeline set up. The Review Apps are based off the Staging App, so the Review Apps are using all the same environment variables etc. as the Staging App.

When the Review Apps try to spin up, I keep getting the follow log error. How come the Review App cannot build, but the Staging App (which is based off) can build no problem?

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.3
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Fetching https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby
       Fetching rake 11.2.2
       Fetching StreetAddress 1.0.6
       Fetching i18n 0.7.0
       Installing StreetAddress 1.0.6
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing rake 11.2.2
       Fetching json 1.8.3
       Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
       Fetching minitest 5.9.0
       Installing minitest 5.9.0
       Fetching thread_safe 0.3.5
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
       Fetching builder 3.2.2
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Fetching erubis 2.7.0
       Fetching mini_portile2 2.1.0
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
       Fetching pkg-config 1.1.7
       Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
       Fetching rack 1.6.4
       Installing rack 1.6.4
       Fetching mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
       Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
       Fetching arel 6.0.3
       Installing arel 6.0.3
       Fetching public_suffix 2.0.4
       Fetching httpclient 2.8.2.3
       Installing public_suffix 2.0.4
       Installing httpclient 2.8.2.3
       Fetching ansi 1.5.0
       Installing ansi 1.5.0
       Fetching execjs 2.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Fetching jmespath 1.3.1
       Installing jmespath 1.3.1
       Fetching aws_cf_signer 0.1.3
       Installing aws_cf_signer 0.1.3
       Fetching htmlentities 4.3.4
       Installing htmlentities 4.3.4
       Fetching rubyzip 1.0.0
       Installing rubyzip 1.0.0
       Fetching thor 0.19.1
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Fetching sass 3.4.22
       Installing sass 3.4.22
       Fetching browser 2.5.1
       Installing browser 2.5.1
       Using bundler 1.15.2
       Fetching unf_ext 0.0.7.2
       Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.2 with native extensions
       Fetching netrc 0.11.0
       Installing netrc 0.11.0
       Fetching coffee-script-source 1.10.0
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
       Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
       Fetching dalli 2.7.6
       Installing dalli 2.7.6
       Fetching declarative 0.0.9
       Fetching declarative-option 0.1.0
       Installing declarative 0.0.9
       Installing declarative-option 0.1.0
       Fetching excon 0.61.0
       Fetching multipart-post 2.0.0
       Installing multipart-post 2.0.0
       Installing excon 0.61.0
       Fetching geocoder 1.5.0
       Installing geocoder 1.5.0
       Fetching multi_json 1.12.1
       Installing multi_json 1.12.1
       Fetching jwt 1.5.6
       Fetching little-plugger 1.1.4
       Installing jwt 1.5.6
       Installing little-plugger 1.1.4
       Fetching memoist 0.16.0
       Installing memoist 0.16.0
       Fetching os 0.9.6
       Fetching hurley 0.2
       Installing os 0.9.6
       Installing hurley 0.2
       Fetching uber 0.1.0
       Installing uber 0.1.0
       Fetching retriable 3.1.1
       Installing retriable 3.1.1
       Fetching moneta 0.8.1
       Fetching http-form_data 1.0.3
       Installing http-form_data 1.0.3
       Installing moneta 0.8.1
       Fetching http_parser.rb 0.6.0
       Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
       Fetching nesty 1.0.2
       Installing nesty 1.0.2
       Fetching model_attribute 3.2.0
       Installing model_attribute 3.2.0
       Fetching multi_fetch_fragments 0.0.17
       Installing multi_fetch_fragments 0.0.17
       Fetching mustache 1.0.3
       Installing mustache 1.0.3
       Fetching net-http-persistent 2.9.4
       Installing net-http-persistent 2.9.4
       Fetching nickel 0.1.6
       Installing nickel 0.1.6
       Fetching pg 0.18.4
       Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
       Fetching phone 1.2.3
       Installing phone 1.2.3
       Fetching pusher-signature 0.1.8
       Installing pusher-signature 0.1.8
       Fetching rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
       Fetching rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
       Fetching remotipart 1.2.1
       Installing remotipart 1.2.1
       Fetching rumoji 0.5.0
       Installing rumoji 0.5.0
       Fetching tilt 2.0.5
       Installing tilt 2.0.5
       Fetching spellingbee 0.0.2
       Installing spellingbee 0.0.2
       Fetching turbolinks-source 5.0.0
       Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
       Fetching wicked_pdf 1.1.0
       Installing wicked_pdf 1.1.0
       Fetching wkhtmltopdf-heroku 2.12.4.0
       Fetching tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Fetching memoizable 0.4.2
       Installing memoizable 0.4.2
       Fetching nokogiri 1.6.8
       Installing wkhtmltopdf-heroku 2.12.4.0
       Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
       Fetching rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       current directory:
       /tmp/build_db9f24d052d7c3b0fc0a6d8f7a7bec58/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
       /tmp/build_db9f24d052d7c3b0fc0a6d8f7a7bec58/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby -r
       ./siteconf20190219-234-1ecip0x.rb extconf.rb
       creating Makefile

       current directory:
       /tmp/build_db9f24d052d7c3b0fc0a6d8f7a7bec58/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
       make "DESTDIR=" clean

       current directory:
       /tmp/build_db9f24d052d7c3b0fc0a6d8f7a7bec58/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
       make "DESTDIR="
       compiling generator.c
       generator.c: In function ‘generate_json’:
       generator.c:861:25: error: ‘rb_cFixnum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
            } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                                ^
       generator.c:861:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for
       each function it appears in
       generator.c:863:25: error: ‘rb_cBignum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
            } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                                ^
       generator.c: At top level:
       cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign" [enabled by
       default]
       cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-constant-logical-operand"
       [enabled by default]
       cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-parentheses-equality"
       [enabled by default]
       cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-tautological-compare"
       [enabled by default]
       make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

       make failed, exit code 2

       Gem files will remain installed in
       /tmp/build_db9f24d052d7c3b0fc0a6d8f7a7bec58/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/json-1.8.3
       for inspection.
       Results logged to
       /tmp/build_db9f24d052d7c3b0fc0a6d8f7a7bec58/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out

       An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.

       In Gemfile:
         postmark-rails was resolved to 0.13.0, which depends on
           actionmailer was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
             actionpack was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
               actionview was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
                 rails-dom-testing was resolved to 1.0.7, which depends on
                   rails-deprecated_sanitizer was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
                     activesupport was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
                       json
       Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Fetching https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby
       Fetching rake 11.2.2
       Fetching StreetAddress 1.0.6
       Fetching i18n 0.7.0
       Installing StreetAddress 1.0.6
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing rake 11.2.2
       Fetching json 1.8.3
       Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
       Fetching minitest 5.9.0
       Installing minitest 5.9.0
       Fetching thread_safe 0.3.5
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
       Fetching builder 3.2.2
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Fetching erubis 2.7.0
       Fetching mini_portile2 2.1.0
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
       Fetching pkg-config 1.1.7
       Installing pkg-config 1.1.7
       Fetching rack 1.6.4
       Installing rack 1.6.4
       Fetching mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
       Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
       Fetching arel 6.0.3
       Installing arel 6.0.3
       Fetching public_suffix 2.0.4
       Fetching httpclient 2.8.2.3
       Installing public_suffix 2.0.4
       Installing httpclient 2.8.2.3
       Fetching ansi 1.5.0
       Installing ansi 1.5.0
       Fetching execjs 2.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Fetching jmespath 1.3.1
       Installing jmespath 1.3.1
       Fetching aws_cf_signer 0.1.3
       Installing aws_cf_signer 0.1.3
       Fetching htmlentities 4.3.4
       Installing htmlentities 4.3.4
       Fetching rubyzip 1.0.0
       Installing rubyzip 1.0.0
       Fetching thor 0.19.1
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Fetching sass 3.4.22
       Installing sass 3.4.22
       Fetching browser 2.5.1
       Installing browser 2.5.1
       Using bundler 1.15.2
       Fetching unf_ext 0.0.7.2
       Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.2 with native extensions
       Fetching netrc 0.11.0
       Installing netrc 0.11.0
       Fetching coffee-script-source 1.10.0
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0
       Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
       Fetching dalli 2.7.6
       Installing dalli 2.7.6
       Fetching declarative 0.0.9
       Fetching declarative-option 0.1.0
       Installing declarative 0.0.9
       Installing declarative-option 0.1.0
       Fetching excon 0.61.0
       Fetching multipart-post 2.0.0
       Installing multipart-post 2.0.0
       Installing excon 0.61.0
       Fetching geocoder 1.5.0
       Installing geocoder 1.5.0
       Fetching multi_json 1.12.1
       Installing multi_json 1.12.1
       Fetching jwt 1.5.6
       Fetching little-plugger 1.1.4
       Installing jwt 1.5.6
       Installing little-plugger 1.1.4
       Fetching memoist 0.16.0
       Installing memoist 0.16.0
       Fetching os 0.9.6
       Fetching hurley 0.2
       Installing os 0.9.6
       Installing hurley 0.2
       Fetching uber 0.1.0
       Installing uber 0.1.0
       Fetching retriable 3.1.1
       Installing retriable 3.1.1
       Fetching moneta 0.8.1
       Fetching http-form_data 1.0.3
       Installing http-form_data 1.0.3
       Installing moneta 0.8.1
       Fetching http_parser.rb 0.6.0
       Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
       Fetching nesty 1.0.2
       Installing nesty 1.0.2
       Fetching model_attribute 3.2.0
       Installing model_attribute 3.2.0
       Fetching multi_fetch_fragments 0.0.17
       Installing multi_fetch_fragments 0.0.17
       Fetching mustache 1.0.3
       Installing mustache 1.0.3
       Fetching net-http-persistent 2.9.4
       Installing net-http-persistent 2.9.4
       Fetching nickel 0.1.6
       Installing nickel 0.1.6
       Fetching pg 0.18.4
       Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions
       Fetching phone 1.2.3
       Installing phone 1.2.3
       Fetching pusher-signature 0.1.8
       Installing pusher-signature 0.1.8
       Fetching rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
       Fetching rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
       Fetching remotipart 1.2.1
       Installing remotipart 1.2.1
       Fetching rumoji 0.5.0
       Installing rumoji 0.5.0
       Fetching tilt 2.0.5
       Installing tilt 2.0.5
       Fetching spellingbee 0.0.2
       Installing spellingbee 0.0.2
       Fetching turbolinks-source 5.0.0
       Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
       Fetching wicked_pdf 1.1.0
       Installing wicked_pdf 1.1.0
       Fetching wkhtmltopdf-heroku 2.12.4.0
       Fetching tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Fetching memoizable 0.4.2
       Installing memoizable 0.4.2
       Fetching nokogiri 1.6.8
       Installing wkhtmltopdf-heroku 2.12.4.0
       Installing nokogiri 1.6.8 with native extensions
       Fetching rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

       current directory:
       /tmp/build_db9f24d052d7c3b0fc0a6d8f7a7bec58/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
       /tmp/build_db9f24d052d7c3b0fc0a6d8f7a7bec58/vendor/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby -r
       ./siteconf20190219-234-1ecip0x.rb extconf.rb
       creating Makefile

       current directory:
       /tmp/build_db9f24d052d7c3b0fc0a6d8f7a7bec58/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
       make "DESTDIR=" clean

       current directory:
       /tmp/build_db9f24d052d7c3b0fc0a6d8f7a7bec58/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
       make "DESTDIR="
       compiling generator.c
       generator.c: In function ‘generate_json’:
       generator.c:861:25: error: ‘rb_cFixnum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
            } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                                ^
       generator.c:861:25: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for
       each function it appears in
       generator.c:863:25: error: ‘rb_cBignum’ undeclared (first use in this function)
            } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                                ^
       generator.c: At top level:
       cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign" [enabled by
       default]
       cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-constant-logical-operand"
       [enabled by default]
       cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-parentheses-equality"
       [enabled by default]
       cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-tautological-compare"
       [enabled by default]
       make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

       make failed, exit code 2

       Gem files will remain installed in
       /tmp/build_db9f24d052d7c3b0fc0a6d8f7a7bec58/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/json-1.8.3
       for inspection.
       Results logged to
       /tmp/build_db9f24d052d7c3b0fc0a6d8f7a7bec58/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out

       An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.

       In Gemfile:
         postmark-rails was resolved to 0.13.0, which depends on
           actionmailer was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
             actionpack was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
               actionview was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
                 rails-dom-testing was resolved to 1.0.7, which depends on
                   rails-deprecated_sanitizer was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
                     activesupport was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
                       json
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Maybe too old dependencies? Have you deleted the Gemfile.lock and rebundled?

Comment: Maybe try a newer `bundler`. Have you updated any Gems since last deploy? ALl gems up to date?

Comment: Yes, I dug into the Gemfile and started specifying specific versions that are in my master branch's lockfile. That solved the problem.